# setProperty() returning false

Tags: c++, json, qt, deserialization, moc

I'm trying to convert a `QVariantMap` to a custom class derived from `QObject` but I'm getting the return value of `false` from [setProperty()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) when it comes to set the property of my enum type. Code goes below:

The **MessageHeader.h** file:

```
// deserialization class header
class MessageHeader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MessageHeader(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MessageHeader();

    enum class MessageType
    {
        none = 0,
        foo = 1,
        baa = 2
    };

    Q_ENUM(MessageType)
    Q_PROPERTY(MessageType type READ getType WRITE setType)
    Q_PROPERTY(int ContentLength READ getContentLength WRITE setContentLength)

    void setType(MessageType type);
    void setContentLength(int ContentLength);
    MessageType getType();
    int getContentLength();
    QString toString();

    MessageType type = MessageType::none;
    int ContentLength = 0;
};
```

The **MessageHeader.cpp** file:

```
MessageHeader::MessageHeader(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

MessageHeader::~MessageHeader()
{
}

MessageType MessageHeader::getType()
{
    return type;
}

int MessageHeader::getContentLength()
{
    return ContentLength;
}

void MessageHeader::setType(MessageType type)
{
    this->type = type;
}

void MessageHeader::setContentLength(int ContentLength)
{
    this->ContentLength = ContentLength;
}

QString MessageHeader::toString()
{
    return QString("NOT IMPLEMENTED YET");
}
```

And the deserialize function template helper:

```
  template<typename T>
    T* Deserialize(const QString &json)
    {
        bool status = false;

        QJson::Parser parser;
        QVariantMap map = parser.parse(json.toUtf8(), &status).toMap();

        if(!status)
            return NULL;

        T *obj = new T(); //don't worry about this, I'll rather take this from paramters once this is working
        QObject *p = (QObject *) obj; // cast done so that I see setProperty() method
        for(QVariantMap::const_iterator iter = map.begin(); iter != map.end(); ++iter)
        {
            const char *name = iter.key().toLatin1();
            const QVariant value = iter.value();
            qDebug() << "setting " << name << "=" << value;
            // the issue goes below. Here setProperty() return false.
            // At this point, name = 'type' and value = 2
            assert(p->setProperty(name, value));
        }
    //QJson::QObjectHelper::qvariant2qobject(map, obj);
    return obj;
}
```

The JSON input string to above function is like this:

```
"{\"ContentLength\": 100, \"type\": 2}"
```

The enum type is registered in the `main` funcction before anything else:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MessageType>("MessageType");
```

And here's the [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) library used in this example. I build it on Windows with this [.pro](https://github.com/flavio/qjson/commit/66d10c44dd3b21d693933f320c32b3c9a175a693) file

EDIT:

I just found that the type property can't be find by [indexOfProperty()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#indexOfProperty)

```
qDebug() << "id = " << meta->indexOfProperty(name); // print -1, name = 'type'
```

Comment: False means it couldn't set what you asked it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enum property can only be set if the variant type is either a `QString`, `QInt` or `QUInt` as could be seen [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp.html#_ZNK13QMetaProperty5writeEP7QObjectRK8QVariant). So to successfully set the enum property, the variant needs to be one of these types and nothing else. QJson parses any unsigned integers as `QULongLong` as can be seen [here, line 84](https://github.com/flavio/qjson/blob/d0f62e65f0b79fb7724d8d551dc9ff11d085127b/src/json_scanner.yy). So one way is to fork QJson and modify the code so the integer values are converted to `QInt` and `QUInt` or read/write the enum values as strings.

Also, putting statements within an `assert` is not a good idea, but I assume you just wrote that code trying to figure out the problem.

Just as a side note, according to Qt documentation,

> [qRegisterMetaType] is useful only for registering an alias (typedef) for every other use case Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and qMetaTypeId() should be used instead.

so replacing `qRegisterMetaType<MessageHeader::MessageType>("MessageType")` with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MessageHeader::MessageType)` in your header would be a reasonable move.

Comment: Unfortunately changing from enum class to enum didn't solve. Yes, I just wrote that code trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Jack Ah indeed, unscoped enums are implicitly convertible to `int`, not from `int`. I completely replaced my answer.

Comment: I added the overload and did the move to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` but still didn't work

Comment: @Jack Hmm. I actually tested this approach on my machine. Which compiler and Qt version are you using? I tested with Qt 5.4 in VS 2013.

Comment: Huh, it has been 4am when I was answering last. Actually it works for me even without the overload. See the source file I used [here](http://pastebin.com/ij0RFEnP) and the header [here](http://pastebin.com/BWYsFuKD).  The output for me is "1 2". I looked into the generated `moc` file and there the code is `setType(*reinterpret_cast< MessageType*>(_v));`. So to make this safe I explicitly specified the underlying type of the enum by writing `enum class MessageType : int`. However, it works for me without it too. Could you post what your moc file shows?

Comment: I also fortunately have the debug version of Qt built. What's going on inside is that Qt actually checks if the property is a enum and if yes, it reinterpret_casts the int to the enum type. Also, interestingly, you can pass the string representation of enum value there and it will convert the string to enum value. So you can do `setProperty("type", QVariant{"foo"});`.

Comment: I'm new to qt/moc system, what part of the file should I look at? tell me if this is what you're looking for http://pastebin.com/8ShkzJLY I guess I figured out why this isn't working. I did separed and small test cases and found that this worked, just like your example. But what's different from your example the the `map` is the type being used. For debuggin purposes, I have some code that iterate over all the map and print its key and value, the output is: `"ContentLength" QVariant(qulonglong, 100)
"type" QVariant(qulonglong, 2)`

note the type, it's `qulonglong` and not an int. So,

Comment: if you do `m.setProperty("type", QVariant { (qulonglong) 2 });` it doesn't work. So the real issue is the datatype. I still have't found the solution, how can I workaround this?

Comment: I implemented the overload `void setType(qulonglong type_);` but it doesn't even gets called...

Comment: I did cast the value to `int` from `qulonglong` calling `value.convert(QVariant::Type::Int)` and it worked fine! Thanks for helping and pointing me to the right direction! Here's my working code http://pastebin.com/zNBDw2Lv

Comment: Add the details to fix the issue so that I can accept your answer and this be useful to others

Comment: @Jack Yep. To completely understand what's going on - take a look at [this function](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp.html#_ZNK13QMetaProperty5writeEP7QObjectRK8QVariant) and see how it handles the enum property. As you can see it can convert it from `string`, `int`, or `uint`, but not `ulonglong`. I'm happy we could drill down to this. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Jack I was just curious where does `ulonglong` comes from. It comes from [this file, line 84](https://github.com/flavio/qjson/blob/d0f62e65f0b79fb7724d8d551dc9ff11d085127b/src/json_scanner.yy). You could fork QJson and modify this line to something like `static_cast<unsigned int>(strtoul(...))` as long as all your integer values fit to this type. Or write and read your enums as strings.

Comment: @Jack edited the answer so it could really be useful for people searching for this particular problem with QJson and enum interaction.

Comment: I was reading this source code too, before I was on qobject.cpp checking setProperty()/write() to find answer to my questions. I'm glad we could drill down to this too! Happy coding for you too! :) I've downloaded the source code (as I said, I had to built it myself since there's no Windows packages, so far I know). I'll do the needed changes to make sure the deserialization in `qvariant2qobject()`will work and the cast in the lex file as you mentioned and send the the repo as bug fix. Hope this gets accepted. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Building up on Rostislav's answer, if you have no choice but to receive a `QULongLong` as input, here is a code snippet to convert it if the property to set is an enum:

```
#include <QMetaProperty>

const QMetaObject* meta = object->metaObject();
const int index = meta->indexOfProperty(propName);
if (index == -1) {/* report error*/}
if (meta->property(index).isEnumType())
    // special case for enums properties: they can be set from QInt or QUInt variants,
    // but unsigned integers parsed from json are QULongLong
    object->setProperty(propName, propVariant.value<unsigned int>());
else
    object->setProperty(propName, propVariant);
```